# How to rotate a BitmapSource by any angle?

Tags: c#, wpf

How may I create a BitmapSource d which is the content of BitmapSource s rotated by any angle a? RotateTransform is unsuitable because it is limited to angles of only 90deg multiples.

EDIT: Demo of RotateTransform limitation:

```
        // Create the TransformedBitmap to use as the Image source.
        TransformedBitmap tb = new TransformedBitmap();
        // Create the source to use as the tb source.
        BitmapImage bi = (BitmapImage)capture;
        // Properties must be set between BeginInit and EndInit calls.
        tb.BeginInit();
        tb.Source = bi;
        // Set image rotation.
            var transform = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform(angle:30);
        tb.Transform = transform;
        tb.EndInit();  // "Transform must be a combination of scales, flips, and 90 degree rotations"
```

Comment: Where are you finding that [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) only accepts 90deg multiples?

Comment: @ChrisJJ: `RotateTransform` can be any angle. It's the [`TransformedBitmap.Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.transformedbitmap.transform.aspx) property that only accepts 90° increments (see linked docs). You could use other means to create a rotated bitmap but it'd be somewhat more complicated. Can you use a `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform` instead (as in Paul's answer)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Joe. I'll look into those alternatives.

Comment: Vote for the feature request: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10870098-allow-rotation-of-bitmapsource-by-any-angle

Answer (score 0):

I created a test project in Blend. RotateTransform can be any angle:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <Image Margin="0,0,191,122" Source="{Binding Property1}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="26.565"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

I created the SampleDataSource where Property1 is an image.

Comment: That's strange, because in VS2010 Express C# (.NET, "new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform(angle:30)" fails with "Transform must be a combination of scales, flips, and 90 degree rotations."